# Как можно присвоить Object к element.style?

Tags: javascript

Я знаю два способа изменить element style первый не морочить голову и просто писать все стили через string. Второй способ это использовать функцию Object.assign(element.style, переменная типа object).
Но мне стало интересно какие есть ещё способы изменить element.style с помощью object переменной?
Не рабочий пример:

```
element.style = {
  color : "red",
  border : "1px solid red",
  width : "50px",
  height : "50px"
}
```

Comment: [свойство style - это свойство только для чтения](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) - соответственно к нему нельзя применить операцию присваивания

Comment: Следующий код работает без ошибок и предупреждений: element.style = "border:1px solid red; width:50%;height:50px"; также можно и с Object.assign()

Comment: @Tima25, нужно учитывать, что установка инлайн стилей свойству `style` (а это по сути обращение к свойству `style.cssText`), перезапишет все ранее указанные встроенные стили. Если на это не обратить внимание, то оно может сыграть злую шутку.

Comment: Ну вот как вариант: `Object.entries(style).map(e => e.join(': ')).join('; ')` (Вроде получается алгоритм `O(n²)`). На зачем лепить что-то вместо `Object.assign`, если это и так самый или один из самых быстрых способов применить стили?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно так сделать

```
const obj = {
  color : "red",
  border : "1px solid red",
  width : "50px",
  height : "50px"
}

Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
   element.style[key] = value;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const el = document.querySelector('div');

  Object.assign(el.style, {
    color : "red",
    border : "1px solid red",
    width : "50px",
    height : "50px"
  });
```